# How to avoid "Windows cannot open the required file D:\Sources\Install.swm" when installing Windows 10 from USB drive?

Tags: windows, usb, installation

I run into the error "Windows cannot open the required file D:\Sources\Install.swm" when installing Windows 10 from USB drive.
Installation with the exact same USB drive worked on other machines.
The image on the drive was created by a Microsoft script, so I dont actually know the settings used to install

Please note: The install.swm-Files are roughly 2G in size, so this is not the exact same issue as with the >4G install.wim on FAT32.

Comment: How exactly did you create the image?

Comment: Is the file actually visible from within the Windows installation environment?

Comment: The Image was created from a Windows 10 Enterprise ISO downloaded from the VLSC by the CreateSrSMedia.ps1-Script on the MS Web page (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=867842). MOre information about the script on https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/rooms/console.

Comment: The file is on the same USB stick the machine is bootet from, and the three install.swm-files are in the sources folder (install.swm, install2.swm and install3.swm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-created the image on a different USB drive - works.